# Is it possible to provide some manual data to create private key for the ethereum account?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cryptography

We were trying to provide some manual data to create the private key if I want to create a new ethereum account using this private key.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, if you are using web3.js you can `web3.eth.accounts.create([entropy]); then you can manually input your own entropy.

the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#accounts-create)